# Algpseudocode, for-next loop: control variable in next line

Tags: algorithms, loops, pseudocode, algpseudocode, forall

In this pseudo-code excerpt, is it feasible to add a new argument for the variable *v* with a syntax like `\ForAll {$v$}{$v \in V(G)$}` to get the output *next v*?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm}
    
\renewcommand\algorithmicforall{\textbf{repeat for each}}
\def\algorithmicnext{\textbf{next}}%
    
\algdef{SE}[FOR]{ForAll}{EndFor}[1]
    {\algorithmicforall\ #1}
    {\algorithmicnext}
    
\begin{document}
    \begin{algorithm}
        \caption{The Bellman-Kalaba algorithm}
        \begin{algorithmic}[1]
            \ForAll {$v \in V(G)$}
                \State $l(v) \leftarrow \infty$
            \EndFor
        \end{algorithmic}
    \end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I would like to use only the packages `algpseudocode` and `algorithm` because this is a legacy code project.

Answer (score 3):

With
`\newcommand \algorithmicnext[1]{\textbf{next #1}}`

**the code**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm}

\renewcommand\algorithmicforall{\textbf{repeat for each}}
\newcommand \algorithmicnext[1]{\textbf{next #1}}%<- this line
%\def\algorithmicnext{\textbf{next}}%

\algdef{SE}[FOR]{ForAll}{EndFor}[1]
{\algorithmicforall\ #1}
{\algorithmicnext}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
    \caption{The Bellman-Kalaba algorithm}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
        \ForAll {$v \in V(G)$}
        \State $l(v) \leftarrow \infty$
        \EndFor{v}
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I'd define a proper structure for this kind of loop:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm}

\algnewcommand\algorithmicrepeatforeach{\textbf{repeat for each}}
\algnewcommand{\algorithmicendrepeatforeach}[1]{\textbf{next} #1}

\algdef{SE}[FOR]{RepeatForEach}{EndRepeatForEach}[1]
    {\algorithmicrepeatforeach\ #1}
    {\algorithmicendrepeatforeach}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{The Bellman-Kalaba algorithm}

\begin{algorithmic}[1]
  \RepeatForEach {$v \in V(G)$}
    \State $l(v) \leftarrow \infty$
  \EndRepeatForEach{$v$}
\end{algorithmic}

\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

This borrows from [pascal974's answer (duly upvoted)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/697927/4427), with a variation.

[image]

With a different syntax: you use two arguments in `\RepeatForEach`, the first being the variable to be pushed in a stack; `\EneRepeatForEach` will pop it and use it. This allows for nesting the loops without having to take care of the variables at the end.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm}

\algnewcommand\algorithmicrepeatforeach{\textbf{repeat for each}}
\algnewcommand{\algorithmicendrepeatforeach}{\textbf{next}}

\algdef{SE}[FOR]{RepeatForEach}{EndRepeatForEach}[2]
    {\pushvar{#1}\algorithmicrepeatforeach\ #2}
    {\algorithmicendrepeatforeach\ \popvar}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \g_alg_varstack_seq
\NewDocumentCommand{\pushvar}{m}
 {
  \seq_gpush:Nn \g_alg_varstack_seq { #1 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\popvar}{}
 {
  \seq_gpop:NN \g_alg_varstack_seq \l_tmpa_tl
  \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{The Bellman-Kalaba algorithm}

\begin{algorithmic}[1]
  \RepeatForEach {$v$}{$v \in V(G)$}
    \State $l(v) \leftarrow \infty$
    \RepeatForEach {$u$}{$u\in X$}
      \State whatever
    \EndRepeatForEach
  \EndRepeatForEach
\end{algorithmic}

\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]